# Valid certificate no longer working when calling through X509Store

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I'm using a security certificate installed in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities in Windows 10 that I use to call an API. The certificate is normally due to expire in more than a year, but the problem is that after a few days of using the API calls, I will get TLS issues, where the certificate is no longer recognized.
The certificate is used through a C# client using the X509Store methods.

```
 private X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate()
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
        return store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, _certificateSerialNumber, false)[0];
    }
```

Uninstalling the certificate and re-installing it usually makes it go away. But the problem is that the certificate stops working faster and faster with every subsequent re-install, to the point that a re-install is needed every day. Maybe someone has had this issue before, maybe when issuing our certificates we did something wrong, and someone could shed a light on it?

Comment: Provide more info please. Is this a CA or self-signed certificate? are you trying to use mutual authentication? from which client to where? is the endpoint and Azure API Service? Have you tried to move it to Personal certificates? Trusted root CA store is only used for root CA's as the name says not for issued certificates, so unless you have a CA provider it has no sense to install it in that store.

Comment: This is a CA certificate issued by the Energy Reliability Council of Texas. This is intended to be used for mutual authentication, I do have an accompanying server authentication certificate, which causes no problems at the moment. the client is mainly an Excel add-in programmed in C#, and I communicate to the server in Texas using a VPN as a US IP. No, this is not an Azure API service, it's quite an old SOAP based API from the late 2000's. No, I haven't moved it to Personal certificates, because the problem is not that it won't work, it's just that it stops working before the expiration date.

Comment: have you access to the SOAP API code? this certificate must be used by both sides, client and Api. Do you have any trace? TLS 1.1 is deprecated so communication should be established using TLS 1.2 and your client and API code should be able to handle this protocol. Doubt it is a certificate installation, instead check if certificate is the same in the client and server side and protocol using is the same.